# DataGridViewImageColumn doesn't change value

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewimagecolumn

I'm trying to change the image of a cell inside DataGridViewImageColumn when the value of another cell is OK or NO.
I've created the column with this code

```
Dim NewImageProd As New DataGridViewImageColumn
NewImageProd.Image = My.Resources.Smile1
NewImageProd.Name = "IMAGE"
NewImageProd.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom
NewImageProd.DisplayIndex = 0
NewImageProd.Width = 70
DGDati.Columns.Add(NewImageProd)
```

Later I've done the check with this code

```
For Idx = 0 To DGDati.RowCount - 1
    Select Case DGDati("OTHERVALUE", Idx).Value.ToString
        Case "OK"
            DGDati.Rows(Idx).Cells("IMAGE").Value = My.Resources.Smile2
        Case "NO"
            DGDati.Rows(Idx).Cells("IMAGE").Value = My.Resources.Smile3
    End Select
Next
Call DGDati.RefreshEdit()
```

But nothing happen.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try trimming the string before comparison.

Comment: @preciousbetine It enters in the Case, but it doesn't set the new value :/

Comment: Never reuse images from Resources like that.  `Resources` is a factory not a collection.  That means it is creating a new, unique object each time, which is overkill and causes your app to leak. Store them in a n array and load from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataGridView.CellFormatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting) event that occurs when the contents of a cell need to be formatted for display. Using this event you don't need to refresh `DataGridView` or data.

```
Private Sub DGDati_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DGDati.CellFormatting

    If e.ColumnIndex = -1 Or e.RowIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

    With Me.DGDati
        If .Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "IMAGE" Then
            If .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("OTHER_VALUE").Value = "OK" Then
                e.Value = My.Resources.Smile2
            ElseIf .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("OTHER_VALUE").Value = "NO"
                e.Value = My.Resources.Smile3
            Else
                e.Value = My.Resources.Smile1
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Also follow advice in the comments to never reuse images from `Resources` like that.